# issue with converting dates in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have an issue with displying a date in a certain format. The date is stored in my database like that :`"01092014`" how can I convert it to `"09/01/2014"` in PHP ? Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Also, stop storing your dates as useless strings. And that Jan 9th? Or Sept 1st?

Comment: Is it stored as an integer or a string?

Comment: it is stored as a string and it is january 9.

Comment: please use one of the proper date field types (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html - if using mysql)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('01092014', 'dmY');
echo $dt->format('m/d/Y');
```

If you're using PHP < 5.3 you'll want to consider doing the conversion in the SQL query:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(datecol, "%d%M%Y") as datecol
```

The ugliest one-liner ever:

```
echo date('m/d/Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, substr('01092014', 0, 2), substr('01092014', 2, 2), substr('01092014', -4)));
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/whAUWQ)

Comment: I get a "Call to undefined method DateTime::createfromformat()" using this

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: That's another problem. I updated my answer to show you how to do it in SQL. (I think) it's simpler than the PHP code you'd need.

Comment: actually it's not in a DB I just wanted to make it simple for you guys , it's a date added at the end of a csv file (slashes are not allowed) so my file has a name_date like : file1_09012014

Comment: how does lting make it easier for us?

Comment: Last update. I promise.